# Redshift Extract String Between Two Patterns (regexp_substr)

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to extract the text following `deviceSerialNumber=` that occurs until either a `&` or the end of the string. Data looks like

> someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=device12345&anotherField=moreData
>   someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=deviceabcd

I've tried this

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(session_tags || '&', 'deviceSerialNumber(.*)&') from table
```

but, this returns all of the text until the final `&` (which is the end of the string, since I'm appending a `&` for pattern matching purposes). How do I have to modify this regular expression to extract only the text until the first `&`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it is late to respond, but here is solution that worked for me.

```
select regexp_substr(
    'someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=device12345&anotherField=moreData ', 
    'deviceSerialNumber=(.*)&', 0, 1, 'e');
```

Comment: this is the right solution (i.e. using the `e` param to match on the subexpression). unfortunate that this answer is buried behind others.

Comment: can you please let me know, How do i stop at first '&' and not let it go to end ?

Answer (score 1):

Use occurence parameter

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(session_tags, 'deviceSerialNumber=(.+?)&',1,1) from table
```

Or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(session_tags,(?<=deviceSerialNumber=)(.*?)(?=&)) from table
```

`.*` will match till the last & and `.*?` will match till the first &

Comment: Hmm, this looked promising, but it still seems to be extracting all the text until the final occurrence of `&`

Comment: deviceSerialNumber=(.+?)& should do it.You might have to use replace deviceSerialNumber= in the final select.

Comment: Now, I'm getting a `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator` error. Got it a bunch earlier when I trying other solutions that are on the net. Wondering if it's something specific about the redshift implementation

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same `Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator` with `regexp_substr`.

The work around I eventually settled on was two nested `split_part`s:

```
select
params, 
split_part(split_part(params, 'deviceSerialNumber=', 2), '&', 1)
from (
    select 'someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=device12345&anotherField=moreData' as params
    union all
    select 'someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=deviceabcd' as params
) tmp
```

Answer (score -3):

Found a hack solution that involves two levels of queries to get around having to use `regexp_subtr`. The inner query uses `substring` and `position` to pull out all of the text after the `deviceSerialNumber` tag. The outer query uses the same two functions to cut off any text after the next `&`

```
select substring(pre_serial_num, 1, position('&' in pre_device_id || '&') - 1) as device_id
from
    (select substring(session_tags,position('deviceSerialNumber' in session_tags) + 20, 40) as pre_device_id 
    from table) a
```

eg the inner query takes

> someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=device12345&anotherField=moreData
>
> someddata&=somedataagain&deviceSerialNumber=deviceabcd

and strips text before the device serial number tag to give you

> device12345&anotherField=moreData
>
> deviceabcd

The second query then strips text after the device serial number tag to give you

> deviceSerialNumber=device12345
>
> deviceSerialNumber=deviceabcd