# How to retrieve values in bracket expression in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to extract values using regex_substr from the field below but it contains [] in the value.

**Field**
FRUIT [BANANA, APPLE], VEGETABLE null, MEAT null

**Result**
BANANA, APPLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this, but something like this should work:

```
REGEX_SUBSTR(field, '\[(.*)\]', 0, 1, 'e')
```

The idea was borrowed from: [Redshift Extract String Between Two Patterns (regexp_substr)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879720/174777)

Comment: Thanks. I realized I need to add \  for special characters